# Waiting for selector time exceeded

Tags: puppeteer

I was trying to  login into this website and scrap data but the website require you to login first then make you choose between play or demo i want to click on one of the the boutons but it is not working the code was good with the login form and login but but as soon as it loads to the game it stack on the play or demo btn and finally it says Waiting failed: 30000ms exceeded

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: ['--start-maximized']
    })


    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(
        "https://habeshabets.com/en/nrgames/spinning_wheel", { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
    await page.type('#login-username', 'xxxxxxx');
    await page.type('#login-password', 'xxxxxxx');
    const searchResultSelecto = 'body > app-root > app-sign-in > desktopsignincomponent > div > div > main > div > div > form > div > div:nth-child(5) > button';

    await page.waitForSelector(searchResultSelecto);

    await page.click(searchResultSelecto);

    const searchResultSelector = await page.waitForSelector('::-p-xpath(//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button)');
    await page.waitForSelector(searchResultSelector);

    await page.click(searchResultSelector);

})();
```

the error is  void this.terminate(new Errors_js_1.TimeoutError(`Waiting failed: ${options.timeout}ms exceeded`));
^

TimeoutError: Waiting for selector `::-p-xpath(//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button)` failed: Waiting failed: 30000ms exceeded